# Node.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: node.js

I'm fixing someone else's previous code and in their code they have:

```
let { sequelize: { models: { User } } } = require('../models');
```

I thought it was because I didn't add "use strict" at the top but I added that and get the error

> `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"`

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: It's unclear what this line of code is even trying to do... This should definitely throw a syntax error.

Comment: can you share the exact code ?

Comment: Have this code ever worked? It looks like he's attempting object destructuring which is not supported in node.js and has been removed from both the ES6 and ES7 specs

Comment: @slebetman Can you clarify the statement that object destructuring has been removed from the specs? Shouldn't this be identical to `let User = require('../models').sequelize.models.User; `? In fact, this works fine in the node (7.6) REPL.

Comment: What version of node are you running under?

Comment: @AJFunk AFAICT it's just run-of-the-mill object destructuring.

Comment: It's a mystery to me why people would VTC this as "unclear what you are asking". What's unclear? He's clearly asking why he is getting this syntax error.

Comment: @torazaburo: Sorry, I was thinking of object spread. Destructuring should work

Comment: @slebetman I didn't know that object spread had been or was going to be removed from the spec, but assuming that's true I'm happy. I always considered it a weird feature that supported bad programming practices.

Comment: @torazaburo: Yeah, last I heard they could not get consensus on how edge-cases should work. On top of that there were loud noises from people saying it's a bad idea

Comment: @slebetman But I note that the [TC39 page](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) continues to show it at Stage 3. Meanwhile, IIRC it's already made it into TypeScript. This is a good example of the fine line TS has to walk in deciding how solid proposals are before deciding to incorporate them.